# Can you create a CSS/SCSS rule for a combination of classes?

Tags: css, sass

Let's say I have the following bit:

```
<div class="class1 class2">...</div>
<div class="class1 ...">...</div>
```

Is there a way to make an SCSS rule that goes something like "for elements with class `class1` and any other classes but `class2` apply these properties". So if by default the divs would have a blue background, I would be able to write something like this and make all divs that are `class1`, but not `class2`, have a red background.

```
.class1 && !.class2 { // invented syntax, of course
    background-color: red;
}
```

I know there are other ways of achieving this, but I'm curious to know if you can somehow do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This does not need a complex sass solution. You can simply use the css `:not()` selector. See the example below -

```css
.class1{
    color: red;
}

.class1:not(.class2){
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  class1 and class2
</div>
<div class="class1">
  class1 but not class2
</div>
```

**EDIT** - The above snippet may work fine, but it may behave strangely in the below scenerio -

```css
.class1:not(.class2){
    color: green;
}

.class1{
    color: red;
}

.class2{
    color: blue;
}

.class3{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  class1 and class2
</div>
<div class="class1">
  class1 but not class2
</div>
<div class="class1 class3">
  class1 and class 3 but not class2
</div>
```

The `.class3` selector comes later in the css, but still the color of text in third div stays green. It is because the `:not()` selector has more specificity. To deal with this, you will have to use `id` instead of `class` like below -

```css
.class1:not(.class2){
    color: green;
}

.class1{
    color: red;
}

.class2{
    color: blue;
}

#id3{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  class1 and class2
</div>
<div class="class1">
  class1 but not class2
</div>
<div class="class1" id="id3">
  class1 and class 3 but not class2
</div>
```

So concluding, the `:not()` pseudo selector will work fine for your situation, but you will have to take care of the specificity of selectors.